# How to Create pdf with zend2 and dompdf

Tags: php, zend-framework2, dompdf

I want to use dompdf for generation pdf document.
i got pdf response with follwing code by using **DOMPDFModule**.But my question is how can i pass variable to the phtml file in order to get print on pdf file my code is as follows

```
    use DOMPDFModule\View\Model\PdfModel;
    ...
    ..

    public function printAction()
   {
    $campaignsList=$this->getcampaignTable()->getCampaignList();
    $model = new PdfModel();
    $model->setOption('paperSize', 'a4');
    $model->setOption('paperOrientation', 'landscape');
    return $model;
    }
```

How can i print that $campaignList array in print.phtml file

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not familiar with ZF, but generally what you do when you're working within a framework is go through your typical MVC structure, rendering your HTML in the view and using a PDF-oriented layout. Some more details on your implementation (and links to resources you used) might help provide a solution.

Comment: after referring several links i  found a solution for passing parameters to view in order to print on pdf. if you add `code`
$model->setVariables(array(
          'campaignsList' => $campaignsList
        )); `code`. then use $campaignsList in view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, you can create the PDF entirely within your action without involving the view(presume this is what you meant when reference your phtml file).

Some example code on PDF generation with DOMpdf :

```
<?php
    // Create a new DOMPDF object
    $dompdf = new \DOMPDF();
    // Set the paper size to A4
    $dompdf->set_paper('A4');
    // Load the HTML
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    // Render the PDF
    $dompdf->render();
    // Set the PDF Author
    $dompdf->add_info('Author', 'I am the Author');
    // Set the PDF Title
    $dompdf->add_info('Title', 'My PDF Title');

    /**
    * 'Attachment' => 1 or 0 - if 1, force the browser to open a
    * download dialog, on (1) by default
    */
    $dompdf->stream($name,array('Attachment'=>1));
?>
```

And the documented usage -  [DOMPDF LINK](https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/Usage)

Comment: Yes! I am agree with you.